# How can we setup the BitGo testnet and livenet?

Tags: bitcoin

How can we setup the `BitGo` `testnet` and `livenet` for the below code?

I want to setup the MultiSig Wallet and want to set up our own `bitcoin` node. But it seems `BitGo` doesn't open the node code for setup.

If anybody has done this so please let me know:

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
var bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');

exports.Environments = {
  prod: {
    uri: 'https://www.bitgo.com',
    networks: {
      btc: bitcoin.networks.bitcoin
    },
    network: 'bitcoin',
    ethNetwork: 'ethereum',
    rmgNetwork: 'rmg',
    signingAddress: '1BitGo3gxRZ6mQSEH52dvCKSUgVCAH4Rja',
    serverXpub: 'xpub661MyMwAqRbcEtUgu9HF8ai4ip'
  },
  rmgProd: {
    uri: 'https://rmg.bitgo.com',
    networks: {
      btc: bitcoin.networks.bitcoin
    },
    network: 'bitcoin',
    ethNetwork: 'ethereum',
    rmgNetwork: 'rmg',
    signingAddress: '1BitGo3gxRZ6mQSEH52dvCKSUgVCAH4Rja',
    serverXpub: 'xpub661MyMwAqRbcEtUgu9HF8ai4ipuVKK'
  },
  staging: {
    uri: 'https://staging.bitgo.com',
    networks: {
      btc: bitcoin.networks.bitcoin
    },
    network: 'bitcoin',
    ethNetwork: 'ethereum',
    rmgNetwork: 'rmg',
    signingAddress: '1BitGo3gxRZ6mQSEH52dvCKSUgVCAH4Rja',
    serverXpub:'xpub661MyMwAqRbcEtUg'
  },
  rmgStaging: {
  uri: 'https://rmgstaging.bitgo.com',
  networks: {
      btc: bitcoin.networks.bitcoin
    },
    network: 'bitcoin',
    ethNetwork: 'ethereum',
    rmgNetwork: 'rmg',
    signingAddress: '1BitGo3gxRZ6mQSEH52dvCKSUgVCAH4Rja',
    serverXpub: 'xpub661MyMwAqRbcEtUgu9HF8ai4ipuVKK' },
      test: {
        uri: 'https://test.bitgo.com',
        networks: {
      tbtc: bitcoin.networks.testnet
    },
    network: 'testnet',
    ethNetwork: 'ethereum',
    rmgNetwork: 'rmgTest',
    signingAddress: 'msignBdFXteehDEgB6DNm7npRt7AcEZJP3',
    serverXpub: 'xpub661MyMwAqRbcErFqVXGiUFv9YeoPbh'
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

All bitgo provides is API for creating wallets and transacting.

Use Bitgo if you either need [BitGo JS SDK](https://github.com/BitGo/BitGoJS) or you need [BitGo Express](https://platform.bitgo.com/bitgo-express/).

For testnet you need to create account on https://test.bitgo.com while for livenet you need an account on https://bitgo.com. After creating accountsyou need to create APIs and implement the code (preferably on NodeJS).

maybe try this https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-node